# Android - ActionBar как назначить свойства кнопки?

Tags: android, actionbar

Иметься в виду, я создал кнопки в ActionBar и вот у меня такой вопрос, как забиндить эти кнопки? К примеру я хочу чтобы сверху можно было с помощью кнопок перемещаться по приложению. Ну например кнопка Onelevel переводила на первый уровень, ну а кнопка TwoLevel переводила на второй уровень. Я не знаю как задать свойства этих кнопок, чтобы они перенаправляли. Подскажите пожалуйста, заранее благодарен.

Comment: что значит первый и второй уровень?

Comment: лучше использовать активити с фрагментами и по нажатию на кнопки менять их (фрагменты). Тогда можно всю обработку заключить в рамки одного класса. Задать свойства - через `setOnClickListener(...)`, после "обнаружения" - `findViewById(R.id.button1)`

Comment: Согласен с Jarvis_J, но исходя из вашего вопроса, похоже у Вас очень мало опыта, потому могу вам посоветовать пойти сюда: https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/228-urok-125-viewpager.html, и изучить сначала немного теории. Как делать, там всё есть.

Comment: и если у вас есть минимальный английский, стоит воспользоваться изучением курса: https://eu.udacity.com/course/android-development-for-beginners--ud837, в принципе английский там нужен только условно, курс построен на видео, а у большинства видео есть русские субтитры. Сам сейчас прохожу)